# Data exchange for Python?

Tags: python, json

Just getting started with Python, but the first goal is to create a web service. I plan on using werkzeug for this, however, all I will be doing is writing a client to interface with it. How would I go about exchanging objects between the 2 systems? Is there anything similar to JSON for Python?

EDIT:
A couple mentions of JSON, but my main problem is that I can't serialize a class? I sort of thought that was what JSON could do?

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

user = User("John", "Doe", 25)
json.dumps(user)
```

`TypeError: <__main__.User instance at 0x02ABBEE0> is not JSON serializable`

I know what you are serializing in JSON isn't necessarily a class, it is an object, but you can still reference it almost as such:

```
    var mailingAddress = { 
     "Address"    :   "123 Anywhere St.", 
     "City"       :   "Springfield", 
     "PostalCode" :   99999
};
alert("The package will be shipped to postal code " + mailingAddress.PostalCode);
```

Comment: Just an FYI: JSON is language independent, despite its name.  Scrolling down to the bottom of http://json.org/ shows that many dozens of languages have JSON libraries. :)

Comment: Your separate question should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to use pickle instead of json -- pickles are Python specific but can handle user classes as well as dicts:

```
>>> class User():
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

>>> user = User("John", "Doe", 25)
>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(user)
>>> del user
>>> user = pickle.loads(s)    # reconstruct the object
>>> print vars(user)
{'age': 25, 'last': 'Doe', 'first': 'John'}
```

If you need a variant that is language independent, look at PyYAML and the YAML spec at http://yaml.org

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Pickle works, but even more so, eventually I plan to add an API so maybe I want to look at YAML.

Answer (score 4):

Python has had native JSON support since 2.6 via the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. Previous versions have had to use external libraries, [SimpleJson](http://simplejson.github.com/simplejson/) being the most common.

Answer (score 0):

json cannot represent arbitrary python classes. It supports numbers, strings and dicts. The latter is really the same as an object in javascript proper, but it ain't in python.

If you need JSON and cannot use pickle because you want to deliver to javascript in a browser, simply json.dump() a dict made up on the fly from your object:

```
json.dumps({
    'first': user.first,
    'last': user.last,
    'age': user.age,
})
```

If you want you can create helpers to reduce some duplication.

```
def dumpObject(obj, *properties):
    data = dict((p, getattr(obj, p)) for p in properties)
    return json.dumps(data)

dumpObject(user, 'first,' 'last', 'age')
```

And probably improve this even further by reflection. YMMV.